# Remember Cascading Dropdown value when navigating away from page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown, cascadingdropdown

I maintain an application for my organization that uses Web Forms.  I have to add cascading dropdowns and I need to have those dropdowns remember their values when I navigate away from the page.  My first dropdown remembers its value but its cascading dropdown does not retain its value when I navigate back.  Any suggestions?

Below are my dropdowns:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate><div class="dropDownSelection">
      <asp:DropDownList CssClass="topicDropDown" ID="topic1" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Load_Section1" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"/>
      <asp:DropDownList CssClass="sectionDropDown" ID="section1" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueFile="ID" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="--- Select Section ---" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList></div><br/>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below are the methods that load the dropdown values:

```
protected void Load_Topic1()
    {
        var topicStore = new TopicStore();

        var topics = topicStore.ReadTopics();

        foreach (var topic in topics)
        {
            var topicListItem = new ListItem(topic.Name, topic.Id.ToString());
            topic1.Items.Add(topicListItem);
            //topic1.Attributes.Add("Title", topic.Description);//only shows description for item at the bottom of the dropdown
        }

        topic1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select Topic ---", "0"));
    }

    protected void Load_Section1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        section1.Items.Clear();

        var sectionStore = new SectionStore();

        var sections = sectionStore.ReadForTopic(Guid.Parse(topic1.SelectedValue));

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            var sectionListItem = new ListItem(section.Name, section.Id.ToString());
            section1.Items.Add(sectionListItem);
        }

        section1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select Section ---", "0"));
    }
```

Load_Topic1 is called on page load.  The values of the dropdowns are stored in session when you navigate away from the page.

Below is how I load the values into session:

```
if (Session["Page"] != null)
{
    if (Session["SubmittedPayment"] != null)
    {
        //shazbot -- they've already hit submit
        Server.Transfer("default.aspx?logout=true");
    }
   topic1.SelectedValue = Session["topic1"] as string;
  section1.SelectedValue = Session["section1"] as string;
  rating1DropDown.SelectedValue = Session["rating1DropDown"] as string; 

    if (Session["Page"].ToString() == "HighSchoolInformation2.aspx")
    {
        Session.Add("Page", "InterestSurvey.aspx");
    }
    else if (Session["Page"].ToString() == "Payment.aspx" || Session["Page"].ToString() == "InterestSurvey.aspx")
    {
        Session.Add("Page", "InterestSurvey.aspx");
    }
  else 
  {
      topic1.SelectedValue = Session["topic1"] as string;
      section1.SelectedValue = Session["section1"] as string;
      rating1DropDown.SelectedValue = Session["rating1DropDown"] as string;
      Response.Redirect(Session["Page"].ToString());
   } 
}
   else
    {
    //they're not logged in, send them back to log in
    Server.Transfer("Default.aspx?logout=true");
    }
```

In the code behind I load session variables like this:

```
protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("topic1", topic1.SelectedValue);
        Session.Add("section1", section1.SelectedValue);
        Session.Add("rating1DropDown", rating1DropDown.SelectedValue);

        Page.Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            ModLangRequired.Visible = false;

            if (!checkModLang())
            {
                Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Like I said up top I inherited this code and I don't have the time for a complete rewrite at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing `Load_Section1` as follows. Notice how we are using `Guid.TryParse` to conditionally load sections if a topic is selected.

```
protected void Load_Section1()
{
    section1.Items.Clear();

    section1.Items.Add(new ListItem("--- Select Section ---", "0"));

    Guid topicId;
    if (Guid.TryParse(topic1.SelectedValue, out topicId))
    {
        var sectionStore = new SectionStore();

        var sections = sectionStore.ReadForTopic(topicId);

        foreach (var section in sections)
        {
            var sectionListItem = new ListItem(section.Name, section.Id.ToString());
            section1.Items.Add(sectionListItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add a new event handler as follows:

```
protected void TopicDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load_Section1();
}
```

Now associate the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to the new handler:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="topic1" ... OnSelectedIndexChanged="TopicDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged" ... />
```

Now you can restore the the page state as follows:

```
if (Session["Page"] != null)
{
    if (Session["SubmittedPayment"] != null)
    {
        //shazbot -- they've already hit submit
        Server.Transfer("default.aspx?logout=true");
    }

    Load_Topic1();
    topic1.SelectedValue = IsPostBack ? Request.Form[topic1.UniqueID] : (string)Session["topic1"];
    Load_Section1();
    section1.SelectedValue = IsPostBack ? Request.Form[section1.UniqueID] : (string)Session["section1"];
    Load_Rating1DropDown(); // not sure if you need this???
    rating1DropDown.SelectedValue = IsPostBack ? Request.Form[rating1DropDown.UniqueID] : (string)Session["rating1DropDown"];   

    if (Session["Page"].ToString() == "HighSchoolInformation2.aspx")
    {
        Session.Add("Page", "InterestSurvey.aspx");
    }
    else if (Session["Page"].ToString() == "Payment.aspx" || Session["Page"].ToString() == "InterestSurvey.aspx")
    {
        Session.Add("Page", "InterestSurvey.aspx");
    }
    else 
    {
        // you don't actually need to set values before you redirect
        Response.Redirect(Session["Page"].ToString());
    } 
}
else
{
    //they're not logged in, send them back to log in
    Server.Transfer("Default.aspx?logout=true");
}
```

My assumption is the above code is called from `Page_Load`. Avoid making any extra calls to `Load_Topic1` as well.

Comment: the session variables are actually Guids.  I'm not sure how to adapt your Page_Load there to handle Guids instead

Comment: Can you post the code that sets the session variables? Are you able to change this?

Comment: I updated my original post to show how I add the variables to session

Comment: I think you need to put the `Load_Topic1` and `Load_Section1` in the code block that sets up the page. Please see my updated answer and let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: What is topicId from?  should it be the id of the topic1 dropdownlist?

Comment: When I select the topic1 dropdown it goes blank and section1 doesn't even change

Comment: So I got it to work.  Thank you so much.  Do you think if I followed the same steps that it would work for 7 sets of dropdowns instead of just 1?

Comment: I got it to work for multiple sets thank you again so much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what's happening is, your cascade dropdown (section1) load it's items on the selection of topic1, and when page refresh, topic1 fetch it's value from managed ViewState and section1 renders blank...

There are 2 solutions:

**Manage it in script**

Store section1's selectedValue in any storage like ViewState or localStorage (browser storage) and on document ready, you can fetch items for section1 against item selected in topic1 through ajax call and set the selected value which is stored in storage. (Sounds much efforts, check below option)

**Manage it in back-end code**

In your Page_Load method, call Load_Section1 and pass topic1.SelectedValue

Don't forget to put Page.IsPostBack condition to avoid error...

Comment: But Load_Section1 has 2 arguments, object sender and EventArgs e

Comment: Pass null for them, it will not effect...
I am sure you are not utilizing any of them in code, are you?